# Why would anyone check 'x in list'?

Tags: python, list, set

In Python one can very easily check if a value is contained in a container by using the `in`-operator. I was wondering why anyone would ever use the `in`-operator on a list, though, when it's much more efficient to first transform the list to a set as such:

```
if x in [1,2,3]:
```

as opposed to

```
if x in set([1,2,3]):
```

When looking at the [time complexity](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), the first one has O(n) while the second one is superior at O(1). Is the only reason to use the first one the fact that it's more readable and shorter to write? Or is there a special case in which it's more practical to use? Why did the Python devs not implement the first one by first translating it to the second one? Would this not grand both of them the O(1) complexity?

Comment: What is the computation complexity of the underlying conversion of a list to a set? I would expect O(n), but I don't know how Python implements it.

Comment: Do you really think a `x in somelist` where `somelist` is very small is actually worse than first converting it to a `set` and then doing the operation ?

Comment: The docs look like they're talking about the complexity of `x in set` when the set is the native datatype.  What's the complexity of `set()` itself?  Is that O(n)?

Comment: Another reason might be that you can't always use a set in place of a list. Lists can have duplicates, sets don't. Data structures to use depend on what your data are.

Comment: @ypercube when you are using the `in` operator that doesn't matter.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
if x in set([1,2,3]):
```

is *not* faster than

```
if x in [1,2,3]:
```

Converting a list to a set requires iterating over the list, and is thus at least `O(n)` time.* In practice it takes a lot longer than searching for an item, since it involves hashing and then inserting every item.

Using a set is efficient when the set is converted once and then checked *multiple times.* Indeed, trying this by searching for `500` in the list `range(1000)` indicates that the tradeoff occurs once you are checking at least 3 times:

```
import timeit

def time_list(x, lst, num):
    for n in xrange(num):
        x in lst

def time_turn_set(x, lst, num):
    s = set(lst)
    for n in xrange(num):
        x in s

for num in range(1, 10):
    size = 1000
    setup_str = "lst = range(%d); from __main__ import %s"
    print num,
    print timeit.timeit("time_list(%d, lst, %d)" % (size / 2, num),
                        setup=setup_str % (size, "time_list"), number=10000),
    print timeit.timeit("time_turn_set(%d, lst, %d)" % (size / 2, num),
                        setup=setup_str % (size, "time_turn_set"), number=10000)
```

gives me:

```
1 0.124024152756 0.334127902985
2 0.250166893005 0.343378067017
3 0.359009981155 0.356444835663
4 0.464100837708 0.38081407547
5 0.600295066833 0.34722495079
6 0.692923069 0.358560085297
7 0.787877082825 0.338326931
8 0.877299070358 0.344762086868
9 1.00078821182 0.339591026306
```

Tests with list sizes ranging from 500 to 50000 give roughly the same result.

* Indeed, in the true asymptotic sense inserting into a hash table (and, for that matter, checking a value) is not `O(1)` time, but rather a constant speedup of linear `O(n)` time (since if the list gets too large collisions will build up). That would make the `set([1,2,3])` operation be in `O(n^2)` time rather than `O(n)`. However, in practice, with reasonable sized lists with a good implementation, you can basically always assume insertion and lookup of a hash table to be `O(1)` operations.

Comment: It would be interesting to actually demonstrate the last phrase of your answer. Show at which size that is actually true.

Comment: Note that for constant set *literals* (which have other upsides, namely being more readable), Python 3.2+ optimizes them in the same way it optimizes constant tuples -- by only constructing the set once and baking it into the bytecode.

Comment: Whoops. That was quite silly of me - I wrongly ignored the conversion and implicitly assumed that would be O(1). Thanks!

Comment: @mmgp: Looks like the magic number, for a reasonable range of list sizes, is if the list/set is checked 3 times (though for either very small lists or very large lists that number goes up).

Answer (score 3):

Let's test your assumptions:

```
In [19]: %timeit 1 in [1, 2, 3]
10000000 loops, best of 3: 52.3 ns per loop

In [20]: %timeit 4 in [1, 2, 3]
10000000 loops, best of 3: 118 ns per loop

In [21]: %timeit 1 in set([1, 2, 3])
1000000 loops, best of 3: 552 ns per loop

In [22]: %timeit 4 in set([1, 2, 3])
1000000 loops, best of 3: 558 ns per loop
```

Thus, in your exact example using `set()` is anywhere between 5 and 10 times slower than using the list.

Just creating the set takes 517 ns:

```
In [23]: %timeit set([1, 2, 3])
1000000 loops, best of 3: 517 ns per loop
```

Let's factor the creation of the set out of the check:

```
In [26]: s = set([1, 2, 3])

In [27]: %timeit 1 in s
10000000 loops, best of 3: 72.5 ns per loop

In [28]: %timeit 4 in s
10000000 loops, best of 3: 71.4 ns per loop
```

This makes the performance difference not as clear cut. Now the relative performance of `list` and `set` depends on the exact values presented to `in`. If they are present in the list and are close to the beginning of the list, then `list` probably wins. Otherwise, `set` probably wins.

Of course, if the right-hand side of `in` was larger, the conclusions would be very different.

Bottom line:

1. Don't optimize prematurely.
2. Always profile on realistic inputs before optimizing.

Comment: i want to know the tools did you use to make this test, i just use IDLE

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do micro-optimisations, you must measure:

```
l.py:
for x in range(1000000):
    3 in [1, 2, 3]

s.py:
for x in range(1000000):
    3 in set([1, 2, 3])

~/py $ time python l.py

real    0m0.314s
user    0m0.275s
sys 0m0.030s

~/py $ time python s.py

real    0m1.055s
user    0m1.006s
sys 0m0.029s
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to convert a list to a set, you need to iterate through the elements of the list, which takes `O(n)` time at best. I believe Python sets are backed by hash maps, which means that they actually have a worst-case time complexity of `O(n)` for lookup operations as well.

Their [wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) seems to agree with this.

Comment: The worst-case complexity of set lookup is actually *very* hard to reach.

Comment: Indeed. Unless you create a hash table that only has one or two buckets for holding keys, which would be silly.

Comment: CPython's dict has no bucket, it uses open addressing. Apart from that, even if there were buckets, you can't influence their number from Python. You have to create a hash function so awful that every key has the same hash. None of the builtin types , so you have to go out of your way and create a type with such an awful hash function.

Comment: Good to know (I'm not terribly familiar with the CPython internals, sorry). You could still have values that happen to collide using the built-in hash function, though... which, as mentioned, would be almost impossible to achieve under normal circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Because transforming a list to a set requires looping through the entire list, which is equivalent in complexity with testing if a list contains a value.

So testing if a value is in a set is faster only the set is already constructed.

Comment: "Equivalent in complexity" is a red herring, since the individual steps can take differing amounts of time.

Answer (score 0):

Let's just try it…

```
import cProfile
```

We choose a big enough test range so we can actually measure something. `2**13` is just some random value.

```
test = range(2**13)
runs = len(test)
wcn  = runs - 1 # worst case n
```

The amount of test runs is equal to the amount of numbers in the list so we can have a nice average value in the end.
`wcn` is the worst case, because it's the last entry in the list, so it's the last entry the algorithm will check.

```
def simple():
    for n in range(runs):
        if n in test:
            pass

def simpleWorstCase():
    for n in range(runs):
        if wcn in test:
            pass

def slow():
    for n in range(runs):
        if n in set(test):
            pass
```

Result for our simple test:

```
cProfile.run('simple()')
"""
         4 function calls in 0.794 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.794    0.794 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.794    0.794    0.794    0.794 profile.py:6(simple)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {range}
"""
```

Result for our simple worst case test:

```
cProfile.run('simpleWorstCase()')
"""
         4 function calls in 1.462 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    1.462    1.462 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    1.462    1.462    1.462    1.462 profile.py:12(simpleWorstCase)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {range}
"""
```

Result for the test where we convert to a set first:

```
cProfile.run('slow()')
"""
         4 function calls in 2.227 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    2.227    2.227 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    2.227    2.227    2.227    2.227 profile.py:11(slow)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {range}
"""
```

Comment: That is obviously flawed, you would create the `set` before doing any of the containment checks.

Comment: This test is about measuring the performance of converting to a `set` before doing the `x in y` check, so we have to do it each iteration. It's simulating doing it everywhere in your project code.